# supervisorctl will not tail a running process

Tags: supervisord

#### Problem

I can't get supervisor to tail running processes properly.  I'm running version `3.0a8`.

Here's my supervisord.conf file

```
[inet_http_server]
port=9011

[supervisord]
logfile=/var/log/supervisor/supervisord.log ; (main log file;default $CWD/supervisord.log)
pidfile=/var/run/supervisord.pid ; (supervisord pidfile;default supervisord.pid)
childlogdir=/var/log/supervisor            ; ('AUTO' child log dir, default $TEMP)

; the below section must remain in the config file for RPC
; (supervisorctl/web interface) to work, additional interfaces may be
; added by defining them in separate rpcinterface: sections
[rpcinterface:supervisor]
supervisor.rpcinterface_factory = supervisor.rpcinterface:make_main_rpcinterface

[supervisorctl]
;serverurl=unix:///var/run//supervisor.sock ; use a unix:// URL  for a unix socket
serverurl=http://localhost:9011


; The [include] section can just contain the "files" setting.  This
; setting can list multiple files (separated by whitespace or
; newlines).  It can also contain wildcards.  The filenames are
; interpreted as relative to this file.  Included files *cannot*
; include files themselves.

[include]
files = /etc/supervisor/conf.d/*.conf
```

And here's the most basic supervisor config file, kept in `/etc/supervisord/conf.d/duder.conf`

```
[program: duder]
command=/bin/cat
```

However, this is what my terminal session with supervisor looks like

```
vagrant@lucid64:/etc/supervisor/conf.d$ sudo supervisorctl 
 duder                           RUNNING    pid 31795, uptime 0:03:32
 supervisor> tail duder
 duder: ERROR (no such process name)
```

any ideas?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Remove the space in "program: duder", as your program is called " duder" now (with an initial space).

Also, upgrade supervisord ;)